# Hash file in chunk with Crypto++ FileSource

Tags: c++, hash, cryptography, crypto++

I have a big file need to hash but my memory is limited if I hash it from the file directly. I want to hash in 2 steps not 1 step. For example, I hash the file in chunk with algorithm `CRC32` first and store in string. And do the 2nd step to hash again into `SHA256`.

Currently I success to hash file in 1 step. But it eats memory and finally return error or crash if out of memory.

To make it not to high to use cpu in loop while. I decided to choose 1048576 Bytes(1MB) as chunk. in this test my console not return crc32 hash.

```
CRC32 hash;
std::string str;
FileSource file("D:/1.exe", false, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(str))), true);
while (!file.SourceExhausted())
{
    file.Pump(1048576);
}
std::cout << str;
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: You are exhausting memory because you store the whole file in string. Simply removing `new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(str))` should fix the problem.

Comment: @zett42 no, if use default true alias PumpAll. it return only 8 length chars only. the real problem is before hash it need to load the whole byte to memory than do hash. so i choose to false 2nd parameter. but i don't know how pass the value from filesource to while and do buffertransformation

Comment: @zett42 for test i choose a file 1.exe that 2MB size. so it will loop twice and generate 2 crc32 hash and combine into 1 string. thats i want. but the documentation so leak example.

Comment: First hashing to CRC32 and then to hash the result to SHA-256 is not secure, so I'm not sure what you're trying ot accomplish here.

Comment: @kelalaka That one is about NaCl, a completely different library. Please double check if a dupe is really a dupe: you cannot expect somebody to switch libraries because of one function; it should be possible to SHA-256 a file without loading everything to memory using Crypto++.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes From my point of view, the problem is completely a coding problem. You are right about having different libraries. Maybe I should say only check the solution here. He only needs to read file buffer by buffer and do a finalize as in this [ardunio library SHA26](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/classSHA256.html)

Comment: OK, so to to bring this down to proportions: the hashing is out of scope, you just want to perform CRC32. The problem with performing the CRC32 w.r.t. memory is out of scope as you currently try to stream. What is left is that your code doesn't return a hex encoded CRC32 value in the streaming code that you've given us. Correct?

Comment: Could you check [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pumping_Data#Filter_Framework) and see if their trick with `remaining` works? I think you're trying to read past the file...

Comment: @lynx - How did you make out here? We added your question to the wiki at [Pumping Data | Keep It Simple](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pumping_Data#Keep_It_Simple). It provides the `ChannelSwitch` trick so you don't need to manually pump to multiple sinks.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a big file need to hash but my memory is limited if i hash it from the file directly. so i want to hash in 2 steps not 1 step. ex. i hash the file in chunk with algorithm CRC32 first and store in string. and do the 2nd step to hash again into SHA256...

I think you should use a [`ChannelSwitch`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ChannelSwitch) and let the library feed the filters. The library uses 4KB chunks by default, and it should keep you well below memory ceilings.

The `ChannelSwitch` can feed the source data to multiple filters so you only need to read the data once. You won't have to worry about writing your own ["tee"-like filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10732926/608639).

First, modify your program to use the `ChannelSwitch` and use the file named `data.bin`. You will create the file below:

```
$ cat test.cxx

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "channels.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "crc.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    try
    {
        std::string s1, s2;
        CRC32 crc;
        SHA1 sha1;

        HashFilter f1(crc, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s1)));
        HashFilter f2(sha1, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s2)));

        ChannelSwitch cs;
        cs.AddDefaultRoute(f1);
        cs.AddDefaultRoute(f2);

        FileSource("data.bin", true /*pumpAll*/, new Redirector(cs));

        std::cout << "Filename: " << "data.bin" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "   CRC32: " << s1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "    SHA1: " << s2 << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Next, create a really big file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=data.bin bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 5.48884 s, 196 MB/s
```

Next, compile and run the program:

```
$ g++ -g2 -O3 test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
$

$ time ./test.exe
Filename: data.bin
   CRC32: 20F45F3E
    SHA1: F0857F8E46112BB08A04D5CE51BDBEA0C4539032

real    0m4.430s
user    0m4.269s
sys     0m0.156s
```

Finally, simulate low memory condition using Bash shell as described at [Pumping Data | Low Memory](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pumping_Data#Low_Memory). Note that we need 12 MB to run the executable; otherwise `libc.so.6` fails to get mapped in by the link-loader. That leaves about 4 MB of RAM for the program and data.

```
$ (ulimit -v 16368; ./test.exe)
Filename: data.bin
   CRC32: 20F45F3E
    SHA1: F0857F8E46112BB08A04D5CE51BDBEA0C4539032
```